# How to disable horizontal scrolling in Mobile Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, scroll, flex4, flex-mobile

I have MXML s:View component that consists of action bar and 3 custom components that are 100% application width. I added a scroller like so:

```
 section = new VGroup();
 var scroller:Scroller = new Scroller();
 scroller.percentHeight = 100;
 scroller.viewport = section;
```

What happens is that I get both vertical and horizontal scroll bars. I want to remove the horizontal scrollbar. The horizontal scrollbar appears to be barely wider than the width of the application. As far as I see my content does not exceed application width.

How can I get rid of the horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you should have to do is set the [horizontalScrollPolicy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html#style%3ahorizontalScrollPolicy) style to `ScrollPolicy.OFF`:

In Actionscript, you set styles using the `setStyle()` method:

```
section = new VGroup();
var scroller:Scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.percentHeight = 100;
scroller.viewport = section;
scroller.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);
```

In MXML, you just pass in a string that the `ScrollPolicy` class defines:

```
<s:Scroller horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <s:VGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Comment: That's it! What was tripping me up was that horizontalScrollPolicy didn't seem like a style. Thanks.